# Trigger works on UPDATE/INSERT but fails when run through BCP (date format issue)

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers, bcp

I have a very simple table - Four columns:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SampleTable]
(
    [item]   VARCHAR(32)   NOT NULL,
    [symbol] VARCHAR(64)   NOT NULL,
    [date]   DATE          NOT NULL,
    [value]  NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_SampleTable] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([symbol] ASC, [item] ASC, [date] DESC)
)
```

To update the table, I use a view and trigger:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[SampleTable_in]
AS
    SELECT [item], [symbol], [date], [value]
    FROM [dbo].[SampleTable]
GO

CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[SampleTable_in_trig] 
ON [dbo].[SampleTable_in]
/*
    Trigger on the insert view to facilitate:
    1. Insertions into the table overwrite (update) any records that already exist
    2. Sparse value updates (if the last value in the series is the same, value is not inserted)
    3. Insertions where value is null are considered DELETES
*/
INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
            /* When inserted symbol, item, date exists and values don't match, update */
            UPDATE u
            SET [value] = i.[value]
            FROM [dbo].[SampleTable] u
            INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON u.[symbol] = i.[symbol]
                                  AND u.[item] = i.[item]
                                  AND u.[date] = i.[date]
            WHERE i.[value] IS NOT NULL
              AND i.[value] != u.[value]

            /* When inserted symbol, item, date exists and inserted value is null, delete */
            DELETE [dbo].[SampleTable]
            FROM [dbo].[SampleTable] u
            INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON u.[symbol] = i.[symbol]
                                  AND u.[item] = i.[item]
                                  AND u.[date] = i.[date]
            WHERE i.[value] IS NULL

            /* When inserted symbol, item does not exist and inserted value is not null, insert */
            INSERT INTO [dbo].[SampleTable] ([item], [symbol], [date], [value])
                SELECT
                    i.[item], i.[symbol], i.[date], i.[value]
                FROM
                    INSERTED i
                LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                    [dbo].[SampleTable] u ON u.[symbol] = i.[symbol]
                                          AND u.[item] = i.[item]
                WHERE 
                    i.[value] IS NOT NULL
                    AND u.[symbol] IS NULL

            /* When inserted symbol, item, date does not exist and value from prior date does not match inserted value, insert */
            INSERT INTO [dbo].[SampleTable] ([item], [symbol], [date], [value])
                SELECT
                    i.[item], i.[symbol], i.[date], i.[value]
                FROM
                    INSERTED i
                LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                    [dbo].[SampleTable] u ON u.[symbol] = i.[symbol]
                                          AND u.[item] = i.[item]
                                          AND u.[date] = i.[date]
                WHERE
                    i.[value] IS NOT NULL
                    AND u.[symbol] IS NULL
                    AND i.[value] != (SELECT TOP 1 [value] 
                                      FROM [dbo].[SampleTable] uu 
                                      WHERE uu.[symbol] = i.[symbol] 
                                        AND uu.[item] = i.[item] 
                                        AND uu.[date] < i.[date] 
                                      ORDER BY [date] DESC)

        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK
        EXEC proc_error_handler
    END CATCH
GO
```

My input data is supplied in a TSV format file, provided in the format `<item>\t<symbol>\t<date>\t<value>` with the date in `YYYYMMDD` format. I cannot change the input format and SQL is raising the `Invalid character value for cast specification` when I attempt to bcp directly into the view (with `FIRE_TRIGGERS` enabled).

If I change the date format in the underlying table from `DATE` to `SMALLDATETIME`, the bcp in works exactly as expected, however my understanding is that this older format should not be used for new work (I want to avoid making this change for various reasons).

Likewise, if I change the input date format to `YYYY-MM-DD`, this works as expected, however as explained, I can't change the source data format and would have to build an extra processing step here to do this

I've tried altering the view, using either `CAST` or `CONVERT` to format the date field as `SMALLDATETIME` and a regular `INSERT` works just fine, but bcp is still not happy, with the trigger now throwing a `Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'date'`

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[SampleTable_in]
AS
    SELECT [item], [symbol], CAST([date] AS SMALLDATETIME) AS [date], [value]
    FROM [dbo].[SampleTable]
GO
```

Digging into this further, when I create that view and use the trigger to redirect the input to a table with all the columns set to `NULL`, the date is being replaced with `NULL` on the input (I assume by the bcp process before it ever gets to SQL)

Does anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this issue, beyond altering the target table or input data?

**EDIT:** The bcp command I am using is `bcp TestDB.dbo.SampleTable_in in test_file.tsv -c -b 50000 -T -h FIRE_TRIGGERS -k`

The data matches this small sample (but many more rows than this):

```
SOURCE  M01 20210813    FOO
SOURCE  M02 20210813    FOO
SYMBOL  M01 20210813    M01
SYMBOL  M02 20210813    M02
DESC    M01 20210813    A short description
DESC    M02 20210813    Some other desc
```

When I change the view to alter the format of the date field (`CAST`, `CONVERT`, `FORMAT`), the date field appears to be sent through as `NULL` values only

Comment: Ideally you should change the data coming in. Perhaps create a *new* view to put the `instead of` trigger on, this one should have `date` as a `varchar`, then you can just convert within the trigger

Comment: What makes you think that the error is coming from the Trigger?  This is an OLE DB error and in this scenario they usually come from BCP and *not* from any triggers.

Comment: @RBarryYoung - The full error text is Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]*** [SampleTable_in_trig], Line 43. Errno 515: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'date', table 'TestDB.dbo.SampleTable'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
SQLState = 37000, NativeError = 3609
Error = [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the input source and your BCP commands I do not have a way to test this, however here is what I would try:

First, change your View definition to this:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[SampleTable_in]
AS
    SELECT  [item], 
            [symbol], 
            CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8), [date], 112) AS [date],
            [value]
    FROM [dbo].[SampleTable]
GO
```

Then change the trigger definition to this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[SampleTable_in_trig] 
ON [dbo].[SampleTable_in]
/*
    Trigger on the insert view to facilitate:
    1. Insertions into the table overwrite (update) any records that already exist
    2. Sparse value updates (if the last value in the series is the same, value is not inserted)
    3. Insertions where value is null are considered DELETES
*/
INSTEAD OF INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

    BEGIN TRY
        BEGIN TRANSACTION
            /* When inserted symbol, item, date exists and values don't match, update */
            UPDATE u
            SET [value] = i.[value]
            FROM [dbo].[SampleTable] u
            INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON u.[symbol] = i.[symbol]
                                  AND u.[item] = i.[item]
                                  AND u.[date] = CONVERT(DATE, i.[date], 112)
            WHERE i.[value] IS NOT NULL
              AND i.[value] != u.[value]

            /* When inserted symbol, item, date exists and inserted value is null, delete */
            DELETE [dbo].[SampleTable]
            FROM [dbo].[SampleTable] u
            INNER JOIN INSERTED i ON u.[symbol] = i.[symbol]
                                  AND u.[item] = i.[item]
                                  AND u.[date] = CONVERT(DATE, i.[date], 112)
            WHERE i.[value] IS NULL

            /* When inserted symbol, item does not exist and inserted value is not null, insert */
            INSERT INTO [dbo].[SampleTable] ([item], [symbol], [date], [value])
                SELECT
                    i.[item], i.[symbol], CONVERT(DATE, i.[date], 112), i.[value]
                FROM
                    INSERTED i
                LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                    [dbo].[SampleTable] u ON u.[symbol] = i.[symbol]
                                          AND u.[item] = i.[item]
                WHERE 
                    i.[value] IS NOT NULL
                    AND u.[symbol] IS NULL

            /* When inserted symbol, item, date does not exist and value from prior date does not match inserted value, insert */
            INSERT INTO [dbo].[SampleTable] ([item], [symbol], [date], [value])
                SELECT
                    i.[item], i.[symbol], CONVERT(DATE, i.[date], 112), i.[value]
                FROM
                    INSERTED i
                LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                    [dbo].[SampleTable] u ON u.[symbol] = i.[symbol]
                                          AND u.[item] = i.[item]
                                          AND u.[date] = CONVERT(DATE, i.[date], 112)
                WHERE
                    i.[value] IS NOT NULL
                    AND u.[symbol] IS NULL
                    AND i.[value] != (SELECT TOP 1 [value] 
                                      FROM [dbo].[SampleTable] uu 
                                      WHERE uu.[symbol] = i.[symbol] 
                                        AND uu.[item] = i.[item] 
                                        AND uu.[date] < CONVERT(DATE, i.[date], 112)
                                      ORDER BY [date] DESC)

        COMMIT TRANSACTION
    END TRY

    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
            ROLLBACK
        --EXEC proc_error_handler
    END CATCH
GO
```

To summarize, I do not think that this is a problem with your trigger, rather it is a problem with either your BCP command and/or the View definition.  In short, BCP cannot figure out how to turn your YYYYMMDD input strings into Date datatypes.  The simple answer is to take that problem away from BCP and let the trigger figure it out.

---

From the OP's feedback this too put's NULL in the date column.

Therefore, I have to conclude that the problem is that BCP will not write to the [date] column when we modify it because then it appears to be a derived and thus non-writeable column in the view (see the rules for Writeable Views) with no backing store.  On the one hand, making a write-through view with Instead Of triggers triggers like this is cutting-edge T-SQL and it's behavior for cases/conditions like this is not always well-documented.  On the other hand, BCP is one of the oldest tools in SQL Server, that uses an (no longer documented) special interface to SQL server that doesn't always follow INSERT-like rules.

Taken together, I just have to say that I don't think that there's likely a way to get this approach to work the way that you want.  So at this point, I think that your only reliable course of action is to abandon the write-through View with triggers approach and instead use a staging table.

I'd define the staging table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SampleTable_in]
(
    [item]   VARCHAR(32)   NOT NULL,
    [symbol] VARCHAR(64)   NOT NULL,
    [date]   NVARCHAR(8)   NOT NULL,
    [value]  NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
)
```

This would replace your View, and you could either apply your (modified) triggers to it, or incorporate their logic into a stored procedure that runs after BCP finishes.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Unfortunately this doesn't work - When I make these changes the error changes from not being able to cast the date to not being able to insert NULL values into the date field. If I redirect the output to a table that allows NULLs in all columns, the <item>, <symbol> and <value> columns all populate correctly, but the <date> column is NULL

Comment: @SimonPratt Are you sure that the row in question does not have a NULL/missing date field?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. If I alter the underlying table to set the date field to smalldatetime (keeping NOT NULL), I can successfully bcp the entire data set in without error

Comment: @SimonPratt Then the problem almost certainly is that BCP won't write to what it considers to be a computed column because (by writeable View rules) it doesn't have a backing store column to write it to.  You are already pretty far into undocumented features and at this point I think that your only reliable option is to abandon the view and use a staging table instead.

Comment: Ah, I was hoping to avoid that :) Thanks for your feedback, will see if anyone has any other ideas and then revisit creating a staging table or altering the underlying table

Comment: I used your comment about the view and using a staging table to craft a solution by adding a type table and updating the view to replace the `[date]` column with a `varchar` column. This works nicely - do you want to expand your comment into a reply that I can mark as the answer?